# Execute async script in webDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Here is usual javascript, which looks for hidden element.

```
   private RemoteWebElement getItemInSubmenu(WebElement parent, String itemName) {
        String script = "var el = jQuery(arguments[0].getElementsBySelector('div.rich-menu-list-bg>div.rich-menu-item>.rich-menu-item-label')).filter(function() {"
                + "return jQuery(this).text().trim() === '" + itemName + "'});"
                + "jQuery(el).parents('div.rich-menu-list-border:hide').show();"
                + "return el.get(0);";
        return (RemoteWebElement) browser.executeScript(script, parent);
    }
```

I want to make it asynchronous. How to implement callback?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Return an element with JavaScript? Any reason you can't get the `WebElement` directly?

Comment: And the code above is Java, the JavaScript you are seeing is the value of a Java String variable.

Comment: @NilsH, elements are not visible. I can not get their text.

Comment: @Ardesco Yes, indeed, but there's also some JavaScript in there that is executed, as you can see.

Comment: @ArtemYakovlev Where's the callback? If you need the text of the element, can't you return that from the script instead of the element?

Comment: @NilsH, I don't need text of the element. There is a navigation menu with hierarchy structure. I'm trying to find item by text, then make it visible and click it with selenium. (jQuery click doesn't fire onClick event in my case)

Comment: I see. You wrote "I can't get their text", so I figured that was what you were trying. But I still don't understand the "callback" part of your question. Doesn't your script return the element? Normally, I would use WebDriver to simulate each navigation in the menu, and use [wait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) for each expansion.

Comment: I just want figure out how to use executeAsyncScript instead of executeScript.

Comment: In regards to your problem, is the navigation menu triggered by an onClick() event or is it a CSS :hover.  If it's triggered by a CSS :hover you will need to use native events to make it visible, you cannot do it with JavaScript.  In this case you will need to use an Actions() object

Comment: @Ardesco, you're right. Menu elements become visible with :hover. This method works perfectly, but it is blocking another js. Thats why I decided to make it asynchronous, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

These are pulled directly from the Selenium JavaDoc which is available here:

http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html

Example #1: Performing a sleep in the browser under test.

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeAsyncScript("window.setTimeout(arguments[arguments.length - 1], 500);");
System.out.println("Elapsed time: " + System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
```

Example #2: Synchronizing a test with an AJAX application

```
WebElement composeButton = driver.findElement(By.id("compose-button"));
composeButton.click();
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeAsyncScript(
  "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];" +
  "mailClient.getComposeWindowWidget().onload(callback);");
driver.switchTo().frame("composeWidget");
driver.findElement(By.id("to")).sendKeys("bog@example.com");
```

Example #3: Injecting a XMLHttpRequest and waiting for the result:

```
Object response = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeAsyncScript(
    "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];" +
    "var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();" +
    "xhr.open('GET', '/resource/data.json', true);" +
    "xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {" +
    "  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {" +
    "    callback(xhr.responseText);" +
    "  }" +
    "}" +
    "xhr.send();");
JSONObject json = new JSONObject((String) response);
assertEquals("cheese", json.getString("food"));
```